# How to get the signal like currentCharFormatChanged from QGraphicsTextItem variable

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qgraphicstextitem

I am implementing a text editor by `Qt`. Since I added the editor to a `QGraphicsScene`, I chose `QGraphicsTextItem` to implement it. However, I want to change the status of some tool buttons(like "bold", "italic", "font", etc) when the cursor change. The problem is that in `QGraphicsTextItem` there is no such signal like "`currentCharFormatChanged(QTextCharFormat)`" in `QTextEdit`. How to get the signal when the position of cursor changed?

Comment: You have to implement your custom QGraphicsTextItem. Let's start by implement:  virtual void inputMethodEvent(QInputMethodEvent * event)
and virtual QVariant inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery query) const.  You could install your event filter in this element and handle every iteraction on it. Add a custom signal to handle your QTextCharFormatChanged event.